# Emacs Speaks Statistic - How to retrieve last command in console?

Tags: emacs

In Rstudio I simply hit the up arrow to cycle through recent commands I submitted in console. Is there similar functionality in ESS?

Answer (score 0):

The usual keys for this sort of thing in Emacs are `M-p`/`M-n` and `C-<up>`/`C-<down>`.

Answer (score 0):

In the R console window, `C-p` and `C-n` will cycle up and down previous commands